# Where is Panchito's Guitar?

Tags: guacamelee-2

In Villachula in the land of the living, Panchito the mariachi has a chest behind him but his manager won't let me through as long as he's alive and without his guitar. Panchito says Maria lent his guitar to Gabriela, but she died.

[image]

The lady at the nearby El Pollo Gordo also mentions this saying that she should visit Gabriela's grave, but I don't know where that is.

[image]

Where can I find Gabriela? Where can I find Panchito's guitar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gabriela's grave is at the left end of town, just past the save point. There's a friend of Gabriela's standing by her grave. There's no guitar there, but if you switch to the land of the dead, Gabriela will be right there.

[image]

If you speak to her, she will mention she gave it to a man who is now standing by the fountain. If you go and speak with him, he will say he returned the guitar to Panchito. If you go back, you'll find that Panchito has passed and the manager will now let you through.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit more to this answer.

First, you must find an old lady in a small house.  Go to El Pollo Gordo in the east side of town.  An old woman tells you she lent it.

Then follow the instructions as per Jeff Mercado.

Comment: To be fair, it was already stated in the question.